Azure Function App .Net 8 version not able to bind the ServiceBusTrigger connection string value from appsettings.json
I have my servicebustrigger connection string in the appsettings.json file. function app 8 version can't able to bind the value.
Here is appsettings.json file
approach 1:
`{
 
  "keyVault": "https://abc/",
  "NormalTopicName": "abc",
  "NormalTelemetrySubscriptionName": "abc",
  "ServiceBusConnection": "connectionstring-value",
}`

approach 2:
`{
 
  "keyVault": "https://abc/",
  "NormalTopicName": "abc",
  "NormalTelemetrySubscriptionName": "abc",
  "ServiceBusConnection": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=abc;SecretName=abc--secret)",
}`


Approach 2 works fine. When I do the same in the localsettings.json file.
Here is localsettings.json file
`{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated", 
    "keyVault": "https://abc/"
    "NormalTopicName": "abc",
    "NormalTelemetrySubscriptionName": "abc",
    "ServiceBusConnection": "@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=abc;SecretName=abc--secret)",
  }

}`

Here is function code:
 public class Function1
 {
     private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;
     private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
     private const string RawTopicNameSetting = "RawTopicName";
     private const string RawSubscriptionNameSetting = "RawSubscriptionName";
     private const string ServiceBusConnectionSetting = "ServiceBusConnection";

     public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
     {
         _logger = logger;
         _configuration = configuration;
     }

     [Function(nameof(Function1))]
     public async Task Run(
         [ServiceBusTrigger(RawTopicNameSetting, RawSubscriptionNameSetting, Connection =ServiceBusConnectionSetting)]
         ServiceBusReceivedMessage message,
         ServiceBusMessageActions messageActions)
     {
         _logger.LogInformation("I am Logger");
         await messageActions.CompleteMessageAsync(message);
     }
 }

I have tried with localsettings.json it seem to be working fine. After moving the key pair value to the appsettings.json file not working as expected.
I have already make sure that value are loaded properly in the configuration from the appsettings. The major issue with Azure function binding with .net 8 isolated process.

Appsettings.json works only when reading the settings such as secrets, keys etc., in the function code like:
 var connectionString = _configuration["ServiceBus"]

But it doesn't work in case of reading connection strings in the function signature, because the function signature looks for the environment variables in local.settings.json refer MSDOC:
ServiceBusTrigger("%queuename%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")

As mentioned in SO by @Silent,

Reading the  local.settings.json  when running locally, is part of the debugging experience of the Functions core tools.

And when running the function in Azure, add the connection strings under FunctionApp=>Settings=>Environment Variables=>App Settings. This provides additional features such as Key Vault references.
I have added the key vault reference of service bus connection string as App Setting under Function App=>Environment Variables:
ServiceBusConnection= @Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://keyvaultname.vault.azure.net/secrets/secret2/5d1ab934e83d4762903c31f8df7551de)


I have used your function code and deployed to Azure function app.
Function App response:

